# Escape square brackets from Like statement in two table joining

Tags: sql, join, sql-like

While comparing the data which has square brackets Ex: '-[VVE172BUS-3.30]-' I am using below

Select * from ServerOps.dbo.tbl_VmHealth_Firmware
where biosname like '-[[]VVE172BUS-3.30]-'

AND i am getting the right outout however I need to compare biosname '-[VVE172BUS-3.30]-' with another column from different table. Could you pls help me how to escape the [] while joining two columns

```
SELECT VmhostName, ParentName, DataCenterName,VcenterName,
                VF.Manufacturer, VF.Model, VF.BiosVersion, MAX(VF.ReleaseId) AS ReleaseId
                FROM ServerOps.dbo.tbl_VmHealth_Vmhost VH WITH (NOLOCK)
                LEFT JOIN ServerOps.dbo.tbl_VmHealth_Firmware VF WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON VH.Manufacturer LIKE '%' + VF.Manufacturer + '%' AND VH.Model = VF.Model
                    AND VH.BiosVersion LIKE  '%' + VF.BiosVersion + '%' 
                    AND ((VH.ReleaseDate >= VF.ReleaseDate AND  VH.Manufacturer not like '%Dell%')
                        OR  (VH.Manufacturer like '%Dell%'))
                WHERE (VcenterName IS NOT NULL)
              
                GROUP BY VmhostName, ParentName, DataCenterName, VcenterName, VF.Manufacturer, VF.Model, VF.BiosVersion, VF.BiosVersion
```

Comment: what rdbms are you using? mySQL, MSQL server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with square brackets occurs in SQL server, and only with the opening bracket `[`. This is because we can use square brackets to surround identifiers such as table and column names, which allows us to use names with spaces with out any problem, but means that SQL server sees an opening square bracket as a special character when using LIKE.

> ```
> --CREATE TWO IDENTICAL TABLES AND INSERT SOME DATA
> CREATE TABLE t1 ( biosname VARCHAR(100));
> CREATE TABLE t2 ( biosname VARCHAR(100));
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('-[VVE172BUS-3.30]-');
> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES ('-[VVE172BUS-3.30]-');
> ```

> ```
> --WITH THE OPERATEUR = ALL IS WELL
> SELECT * FROM  t1 WHERE biosname = '-[VVE172BUS-3.30]-';
> ```

> ```
> | biosname           |
> | :----------------- |
> | -[VVE172BUS-3.30]- |
> ```

> ```
> --BUT WITH LIKE WE GET NO RESULT
> SELECT * FROM  t1 WHERE biosname LIKE '-[VVE172BUS-3.30]-';
> ```

> ```
> | biosname |
> | :------- |
> ```

> ```
> --WE CAN USE AN ESCAPE CHARACTER IF WE DECLARE IT
> SELECT * FROM  t1 WHERE biosname LIKE '-\[VVE172BUS-3.30]-' ESCAPE '\';
> ```

> ```
> | biosname           |
> | :----------------- |
> | -[VVE172BUS-3.30]- |
> ```

> ```
> --THE SAME RULES APPLY FOR COMPARING 2 FIELDS
> --ALL IS WELL IF WE USE =
> Select * from t1, t2
> where t1.biosname = T2.biosname;
> ```

> ```
> biosname           | biosname          
> :----------------- | :-----------------
> -[VVE172BUS-3.30]- | -[VVE172BUS-3.30]-
> ```

> ```
> --TO USE ESCAPE LIKE WE HAVE THE REPLACE '[' WITH '\[' 
> Select * from t1, t2
> where t1.biosname like REPLACE(t2.biosname, '[', '\[') escape '\';
> ```

> ```
> biosname           | biosname          
> :----------------- | :-----------------
> -[VVE172BUS-3.30]- | -[VVE172BUS-3.30]-
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b68f6a86b68529b8bb5cdda3f2cb45f8)*

Comment: using MS SQL@kendle

Comment: see my examples MS SQL 2014. What version are you using? Does my Test Script work for you as it works in dbFiddle?

Comment: Hi,
like statement is working fine with [] from one table but I need to compare the data with [] with another column from different table

Comment: SELECT VmhostName, 
                 VF.BiosVersion, MAX(VF.ReleaseId) AS ReleaseId
                FROM ServerOps.dbo.tbl_VmHealth_Vmhost VH WITH (NOLOCK)
                LEFT JOIN ServerOps.dbo.tbl_VmHealth_Firmware VF WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON VH.BiosVersion LIKE  '%' + VF.BiosVersion + '%' 
                WHERE (VcenterName IS NOT NULL)

Comment: How we have to escape [] from below
VH.BiosVersion LIKE  '%' + VF.BiosVersion + '%'

Comment: Please see added content for 2 solutions for comparing 2 fields in the where (or elsewhere : case or if?) Use `=`unless you need to use `like` !

Comment: I've rewritten the answer including the examples with one table and 2 tables.